# How to use maximum space available with qooxdoo

Tags: layout, qooxdoo

Hi
I'm using qooxdoo all the way in my app.
And i want to now, what do i need to do to have a widget using the maximum space available.

The thing i want is to have  a widget on the left side. This one should thake just enought space to be normal. And a second widget wich will grow enought to consume all the remaining space on the right side.

Comment: I found a solution. But it's not so great. I had a container to the app root. Then i set width and height of this container to match the size of the bom.viewport. The probelem with this solution is when you rezize the browser application, my application doesn't follow the new size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your follow this link 
http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/qx-ui-root-td5886017.html
you'll have your answer

Answer (score 2):

[You can just rely on qooxdoo's layouting system to do the resizing for you.](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3a%20%22var%2520container%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.container.Composite%28new%2520qx.ui.layout.HBox%28%29%29%253B%250Athis.getRoot%28%29.add%28container%252C%2520%257Bedge%2520%253A%25200%257D%29%253B%250A%250Avar%2520w1%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.core.Widget%28%29%253B%250Aw1.setMinWidth%28250%29%253B%250Aw1.setBackgroundColor%28%2522green%2522%29%253B%250Acontainer.add%28w1%252C%2520%257Bflex%2520%253A%25200%257D%29%253B%250A%250Avar%2520w2%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.core.Widget%28%29%253B%250Aw2.setBackgroundColor%28%2522red%2522%29%253B%250Acontainer.add%28w2%252C%2520%257Bflex%2520%253A%25201%257D%29%253B%22%7D)

The `edge` and `flex` layout properties are what make the magic happen.